# what is Vfb in this datasheet

Tags: datasheet

Beginner here. I'm trying to read this datasheet, and I'm not sure what Vfb is or how it was obtained. See pages 19-20 in section 8.2. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3410.pdf

Comment: Nice device. I might buy a few (hundred.) I see that TI sells them direct, cheap. The "Functional Block Diagram" on page 10 pretty much tells you (which is why they provide that diagram.) It's worth spending some time with it until you feel semi-comfortable with the layout there. There's just enough that you need to think a little, but not so much that it should be overwhelming. The datasheet on page 8 even tries to talk to you in cartoons. The more difficult details may be managing parasitics and designing/choosing the correct inductor to use for better and more efficient behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vfb is your feedback voltage, that's how the current driver IC "calculates" how much current is actually flowing through the LEDs it's trying to drive with a constant current.

The LM3410 will push the output voltage higher and higher until it reaches 190mV across the feedback resistor.